# What is correct way to declare obs type for DateTime?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX.
What is the correct way to declare obs value for `DateTime`

I found only one way, but it setting date to `now()`

```
Rx<DateTime> myDate = DateTime.now().obs;
```

Is it correct?

Comment: yes it Is correct

Comment: you can either use Rxn<DateTime>, because that is nullable and you dont have to initialize it, or you use what you have done and change the date later

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. In the case that you don't want to initialise it at first, change it to `Rxn<DateTime> myDate = Rxn<DateTime>();`

Answer (score 0):

Declare **DateTime** as **obs** in flutter **Getx**, you don't want to initialize it at start. You've to declare like this:

```
Rxn<DateTime> dateValue= Rxn<DateTime>();
```